# Changing the default "View" page when user logs in?

Tags: 6, users

In Drupal 6 when a user logs in, they are presented with a completely useless page that has no information other than how long the user account has existed.

How do you edit this? Can you embed a view or something there? How would I make a [Homebox](http://drupal.org/project/homebox) the default tab? (I've tried using [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) to hide and disable the tab, but no effect -- still has the lousy "History" info.).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module may help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Panels/Pages you can enable the user_view page (admin/build/pages/edit/user_view) and add views or whatever else you want there.

Comment: Having now done a lot more Drupal development, I'd probably use this approach now.

Answer (score 0):

The [Login Tobogan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module will let you direct users to something else when they log in. It has lots and lots of configuration options.

Or you could use a Panel to override the display of the user profile and put the other views you want there.